# get the whole value of powershell objects

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am executing a Get-ADDomain command

I was fetching the output given by the command

And I noticed that it is not giving the full list of objects it is just listing some of those and then end with ... have attached the image for reference

[image: Powershell Output Issue]

I realized it might be problem with the width of the output and it must be using the default width

So while executing the command I also set Out-Width as 1000 but it gives more values but still the same problem persists and increasing the width any further does not have any impact on the output

Is there any way by which I can capture the whole value itself. I have faced this issue with other commands as well. This is the command I executed :

```
Get-ADDomain | Select-Object LinkedGroupPolicyObjects| Out-String -Width 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-ExpandProperty` and work with the objects, rather then converting them to a string with out-string.

```
$LinkedGPOs = Get-ADDomain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects

foreach($LinkedGPO in $LinkedGPOs) {

}
```

Comment: yes it displays all the values but it gets converted to an array is there any chance we can display the whole in comma separated form itself in the string format only?

Comment: Inside the foreach loop you have access to every single linked GPO. So you might output your desired properties with ```write-ouput $LinkedGPO.YourProperty```...